# How to optimise countdown timer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, game-development

Dear stackoverflow community,

I have countdown timer for my double points power up and now I have problem because my code works fine in game,but when timer is active game is lagging , not too much but any lag is not good for my game because the player needs to play smoothly without any unoptimised component..

I have this code and I bet the game is lagging because the code is in update method ( I tried to put it in game manager script but then timer won't countdown so that is not solution )

This is the code ( Thanks to stackoverflow user @siusiulala , who wrote me the working code)
but seems like it needs to be in another method or something because Update method running performance when has countdown inside.

```html
private void Update(){ 
if (isDoublePoints)
        {
            // Countdown the timer with update time
            powerUpTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            Debug.Log("TIMER ISS " + powerUpTimer);
            if (powerUpTimer <= 0)
            {
                // End of power up time 
                isDoublePoints = false;
            }
        }



    }

    public void OnPickPowerUp(float buffTime)
    {
        powerUpTimer += buffTime;
    }
```

I hope someone will give solution to lagg because I saw a lot of games that has power up systems without any laggs inside...

Thank you stackoverflow, without you my game would not ever come to end :)

Comment: Unless the `Debug.Log()` has horrendous inefficiencies or you call it millions of times, there should be no noticeable overhead from this code. Please profile your code to see if your assumption is correct.

Comment: How I can profile my code? thanks for your comment. Debug.Log is called 15 times only..

Comment: [This page in the official documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html) may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what [trollingchar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57001121/7111561) says about the `Debug.Log` is correct.

To use the `[SerializeField]` might be considered as a *dirty and lazy* hack by some people. Because it has the side-effect that it is now *serialized*, that means the value is stored in the assets. It's not bad but if you are exact it shouldn't be done with fields that will be changed on runtime anyway.

Instead you can simply go to the Inspector, open the context menu and set it to `Debug` Mode

[image]

this makes the Inspector not use the Custom EditorScripts but instead reveal all private fields (of `Serializable` types).

For example for the `Transform` component

[image]

---

However way more efficient than using the `Update` method with a flag **at all** would be to rather use a [`Coroutines`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).

Coroutines can be started and run parallel (every frame right after) the `Update` method but the advantage: when a coroutine is finished - it is finished and doesn't continue checking the `bool` flag every frame.

So whenever you pickup a PowerUp instead of setting the flag to `true` rather use

```
StartCoroutine(PowerUpRoutine());
```

and implement a routine like

```
private IEnumerator PowerUpRoutine()
{
    isDoublePoints = true;

    while(powerUpTimer > 0)
    {
        // Countdown the timer with update time
        powerUpTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        //Debug.Log("TIMER ISS " + powerUpTimer);

        // yield in simple words makes Unity "pause"
        // the execution here, render this frame and continue from here
        // in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // End of power up time 
    isDoublePoints = false;
}

public void OnPickPowerUp(float buffTime)
{
    powerUpTimer += buffTime;

    // avoid concurrent routines
    if(!isDoublePoints) StartCoroutine(PowerUpRoutine());
}
```

---

In order to display it in your game you can use a [`Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) or [`TextMeshPro`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.3/manual/index.html) and set the text like e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private Text _text;

private IEnumerator PowerUpRoutine()
{
    isDoublePoints = true;

    while(powerUpTimer > 0)
    {
        // Countdown the timer with update time
        powerUpTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        //Debug.Log("TIMER ISS " + powerUpTimer);

        // set the text of the Text component to display the value
        // for the $ symbol google for "c# string interpolation"
        _text.text = $"TIMER IS {powerUpTimer:00.00}";

        // yield in simple words makes Unity "pause"
        // the execution here, render this frame and continue from here
        // in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // End of power up time 
    isDoublePoints = false;
}
```

Comment: I thought my performance is not good because its checking all the time if the script is active or not.. But i didn't know how i can make courutine for same job. Thank you for helping me with pointing me out to courutine .. 
till now i started timer with isDoublepoints=true; Now i should only call this text to start it ? "StartCoroutine(PowerUpRoutine());" , thank you one more time man you pointed me how i can use courutine.. one more question, Can i display countdown timer in game? You are the best!

Comment: Updated the answer with how to display the text in the game .. also go through the general [UI Manuals](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html)

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, `Debug.Log()` is a *very* expensive method. It *will* cause lag when called every frame. My IDE even highlights usage of `Debug.Log()` in `Update()` as warning because of that. Use this method only for debugging, and then remove.

If you want to be able to see the timer value, add `[SerializeField]` attribute to your field and it will show up in the inspector.

You can use the profiler by selecting **Window-Analysis-Profiler**, assuming you are using Unity 2018.x. It records how much time processing takes, and helps locating bottlenecks.